# Normalizing a complex dataset

Tags: complex-numbers, neural-networks

I am currently working with a dataset which has complex values. I need to normalize it such that I can use $\tanh$ as activation function, which is within $-1$ to $1$. But how can we normalize complex values?.. 
The normalizing should not remove the complex part, but also be normalized.

Comment: Explain more...

Comment: I am not sure what more there is to explain?..

Comment: What's data-set volume? How many points has? How much points are big?

Comment: The dataset consist 1025 rows, but different number of columns. ..
The dataset is stored as a matrix.  All the points are complex values, and most of them are outside the range..  I just need one way of normalize it..

Comment: the complex part should not be removed... but also be normalized.

Comment: Do you want to chat?

Comment: i cannot not enough rep

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51782/discussion-between-myglasses-and-user25778).

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: The problem is that the output layer he wants to use has `tanh` as activation function and the complex numbers are the labels are complex numbers.

The solution is simple: Split the real and the imaginary part and use the neural network for regression on $\mathbb{R}^2$ instead of $\mathbb{C}$.

The normalization is simple:

1. Subtract the mean value
2. Divide by the range of the values
3. Multiply with 2

However, if your range is not limited you should think about removing the `tanh` activation function.

You might also be interested in this [answer to regression with neural networks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41565985/562769).